# MySQL Real Escape String is not Escaping Quotes or Apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP page which pulls data for one or more records in one database (db1) and then adds them as new records in another database (db2). It's almost functional, but keeps failing with a record because one of the fields contains quotes (and apostrophes, and degree symbols). I was using a function to clean each field, before being added to the SQL script, which includes real_escape_string. I thought this function was supposed to take care of quotes and apostrophes, but the output still contains both.

Here is my string cleaning function:

```
protected function cleanInStr($str){
    $newStr = trim($str);
    $newStr = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',$newStr);
    $newStr = $this->conn->real_escape_string($newStr);
    return $newStr;
}
```

And here is the actual problematic field being added to the SQL script in the values(....) part of the insert:

```
($occArr["verbatimcoordinates"]?'"'.$this->cleanInStr($occArr["verbatimcoordinates"]).'"':"NULL").','.
```

Here is the data in the problematic field in db1:

```
31° 28' 18.5" N 110° 21' 22.5" W
```

And, here is the same data after being cleaned and echo'd by the cleaning function above:

```
31Â° 28' 18.5" N 110Â° 21' 22.5" W
```

What am I missing? Why are the quotes/apostrophes remaining?

Comment: you have an encoding issue, not an escaping problem. What encoding are you using in your db?

Comment: You're trashing your text from UTF-8 into something else, probably ISO-8859

Comment: DB2 encoding is latin1 - cp1252, and DB1 encoding is UTF8, so how do I go about fixing this?